# How can I make ONE big desktop icon on windows?

Tags: windows, user-interface, icons, desktop

I would like to make one desktop icon extra big, without affecting all the others. Why? Because I am trying to help out someone with a visual impairment. The reason is that I would like to make it do something special, like enabling/disabling Bluetooth or VPN. A natural alternative would be to have *something* with a small window, already running, but I was hoping to avoid having to program a new UI.

Is it possible to make a single desktop icon larger so that it would extend (lets say) 4 others?
(If not, what would be the better alternative solution?)

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn’t support this natively. You can make desktop icons larger or smaller - all of them, not just one, as you already know.

There might be a third-party program which does this, but I haven't discovered one.